# DocuSign Envelope Custom Fields

Tags: docusignapi

I am looking at automatically sending a document for signing using API and using a HTTP listener with DocuSign Connect for receiving the status of the document.

In the envelope, I will need to parse in certain information (eg. unique identifier for applications use) which I will need to retrieve in the XML message from the DocuSign Connect.

I am looking at using the Envelope Custom Field for this purpose, is this advisable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree that envelope custom fields will meet this requirement. One thing to keep in mind is that DocuSign also supports document level custom fields, as well as per recipient level custom fields.

Comment: Alright thanks. I am looking at using the envelope ID for the purpose of the application. But the other custom fields might come in useful as well. Just another quick question, if for example I am allowing the senders to tag fields (eg. radio buttons to indicate Yes or No), should I be using the recipient level custom fields to receive this result?

Comment: Envelope/Document/Recipient level custom fields are made available to you for the sake of storing/associating additional text metadata with the transaction. The DocuSign tag fields are a totally different concept and the resulting value of the tags are available through an API query of the envelope or in the DocuSign connect notification.

Comment: got it now thanks! was a little confused as tags were named tabs in the API.